# how to build and install pgrouting-2.0 on postgresql-9.3 on ubutntu 12.04 Lts precise?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, osm2pgrouting

I try to build following instructions from this link https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting after downloading from the github. I have done the cmake command and there is my error output:

```
~/Téléchargements/pgrouting-master/build$ cmake --DWITH_DD=ON ..
-- PGROUTING_GIT_TAG: pgrouting-2.0.0
-- PGROUTING_GIT_BUILD: 0
-- PGROUTING_GIT_HASH: d6ed2cb
-- PGROUTING_GIT_BRANCH: master
-- PGROUTING_VERSION_REVISION_NAME: d6ed2cb master
-- PGROUTING_VERSION_REVISION_HASH: d6ed2cb
-- UNIX=1
-- WIN32=
-- POSTGRESQL_EXECUTABLE is /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres
-- POSTGRESQL_PG_CONFIG is /usr/bin/pg_config
-- PostgreSQL not found.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:122 (message):
   Please check your PostgreSQL installation.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

hOW MUST i DO PLEASE?

Comment: When I display the content of the file pgrouting-master/FindPostgreSQL.cmake , i don't have the link  /usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server in my hierarchy file. I just have /usr/include/postgresql which contains many other files, but not the one named 'server', nor the subdirectory '9.3'

Answer (score 3):

First you want to post your question in a readable form, so I don't have to spend time making it readable (already done, so remember for your next question, please).

Second, read the documentation how to compile pgRouting and what is required: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/installation/build.html#build

Third, read the error message, which clearly says what's wrong: `PostgreSQL not found.`

This means, something is wrong with your PostgreSQL installation. If you compiled it manually, then it may be installed somewhere CMake doesn't look for it. If you installed PostgreSQL using some package, then you might be missing the "dev" package.

Comment: you can follow the *http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/doc/src/installation/installation.html#download* step by step.I tried success